# Can only connect to Google and package repositories

Tags: networking

I just did a brand new installation of Raspbian on a Pi3 and have a bit of a weird network issue.

I was able to update the system without issue. But, when I open Chromium, I can only reach Google website, nothing else works. Same if I do a `ping` from the terminal.

I already tried to manually set the router and DNS addresses, but nothing change.

Any idea of what could be happening here?

Comment: How is your RPi connected to the Internet, and are other devices on the same network working?

Comment: When the problem is present then please execute the following commands, edit your question and paste the output of the commands into it: `ip addr`, `ip route` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.